# Confirm box not appearing in PHP calling from controller (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, confirm

I have gone through all the answers but did not get exact solution of my problem so posting this question.

I am trying to display a confirm box on a specific condition in my controller like this:

```
if($old_riochannel_upto > $param_valid_from){   
    echo "<script>if(!confirm(\'Kindly note that a promotional offer is valid between the period DD/MM?/YYYY to DD/MM/YYYY. During this period the prices mentioned in the promotional offer will override the prices mentioned in this RIO\')){ window.location.href = 'index'; } </script>";                              
}
```

But this pop is not displaying even if the condition matches. It is displaying if put `exit` after closing `if` tag.

What I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone face same problem, I am posting the solution which I found myself.

Instead of writing the script tag in echo I just redirected to a different function and there I have called the view where I am displaying this confirm box. Like this:

```
if($old_riochannel_upto > $param_valid_from){        
    redirect('Rio/load_modal_update');
}
```

Then in `load_modal_update` function calling the view file which have confirm pop up.

```
public function load_modal_update(){  
    $this->load->view('rio/modal_popup_update');
}
```

I don't know why it did not work in echo statement though.